# Android 7.0: tombstone tells signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sigabrt, tombstone

I have a large Android application including C/C++ libraries (via NDK/SWIG).

At some point the app crashes and the tombstone file shows:

> signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
>
> Abort message: 'Invalid address 0xbc9b306d passed to free: value not
>   allocated'

Unfortunately it does not tell me which variable is at address 0xbc9b306d. How to find out?

Restriction: unfortunately due to the scale of the code base I cannot set breakpoints in Android Studio.

BR, Rene

Comment: The tombstone should also give you the backtrace. You can use [ndk-stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html) to symbolize the trace and figure out which line is the one with the bogus/double free.